# Global hotkeys: songbird on KDE

Tags: linux, hotkeys, opensuse, kde-4, songbird

I'm running songbird on opensuse 11.2 KDE 4.3.1 on my EEE pc. 
On windows, there is a hotkey thing inside Songbird, so i set META F9,10,11,12 as media keys and it work just fine.

On linux, there is not hotkey thing in songbird, and I would like to set those same hotkeys. I've played around with the Amarok Hotkeys, which are now setup that way, and looked in all the KDE shortcuts, but cannot find a way to add a new program and new hot keys. I know its possible, I did it before once, but the KDE shortcut programs have changed and I no longer see the stuff i used to do it before.

I'd like to do the same to banshee at some point, but Songbird is the important program. Any Ideas? Any way to set those keys to generic media buttons?

Answer (score 0):

This page describes a way to bind global hotkeys to songbird, using the command line add-on. It's written from Gnome, but probably will work from KDE with not much tweak.

http://deepcode.net/global-hot-keys-for-songbird-in-linux

You can use XBindKeys (http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html) to execute the shell commands. I found the reference on another question's answer.

Comment: I've actually seen that article, but in KDe 4.3 there is no longer a way to add hotkeys via command link, as far as i know. I looked all around, where it had once this before, and its all gone.

Comment: I found about xbindkeys, a program you can use to link global hotkeys to shell commands. If VM doesn't provide by itself, you can bypass using it. I added the url to de answer.